# What target is Gas indicating in this scene?

Tags: existenz

In Sci-fi movie *Existenz* (1999), Ted came to Gas to be installed with bio port in the back of the spine to play the video game. Ted saw equipments in the drawer and said these words to Gas:

> Ted: Those are sterilized aren't they?
>
> Gas: Not to worry. You could fire in a bio-port in a slaughterhouse
>   and never generate an infection.
>
> Ted: Then why the clean overalls?
>
> Gas: It's a mental thing. Helps me focus. **The one thing you don't
>   wanna do is miss with the stud-finder**.

The meaning of "you don't wanna do is miss with the stud-finder" is "You don't want to miss (the target which is missing in Gas's dialogue) with the stud-finder". What is that target here?

**The scene in question**

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. For those of us who have never heard of this movie before, can you provide some explanation as to what the stud-finder is? I'm guessing it is not [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zircon-StudSensor-HD55-Stud-Finder-65945/205143494).

Comment: [This](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Zircon-StudSensor-HD55-Stud-Finder-65945/205143494) is what he is referring.

Comment: Thank you for linking youtube video.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you note, the port is intended to interface with the spine, specifically the nerves within it that go up into the brain. The term "stud-finder" is referring to the first device, which he uses for locating the spinal cord so that the port will go in the right location, the analogy being to finding "[studs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_stud)", the supporting beams, behind a wall.

TL;DR, the target is the spine.